# When desiging an activity based authorization system, how should additional conditional checks be handled?

Tags: rest, api, security, microservices

When desiging an activity based authorization system, how should additional conditional checks be handled?

For example, I have the following authority:

```
VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS
```

which allows the user to hit the endpoint

```
GET /company/{companyName}/transactions
```

However, what if my authority `VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS` has other restrictions based on the activity parameters that in fact make the authority effectively `VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS(companyName=company_a)`. I don't want to encode that information into the authority system, and end up with the following new authority:

```
VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS_FOR_COMPANY_A
```

The above authority seems to mix up the filtering of the views and the authority itself which makes everything somewhat tedious and inflexible.

In another example, I have the following authority:

```
APPROVE_TRANSACTION
```

which allows the user to hit the endpoint:

```
POST /company/{companyName}/transactions/{id}/approvals
```

But what if the approval can only be done if the `transaction.amount < maxAmount` in which case, it's even harder to encode this into a new hardcoded authority.

Note that these authorities may also be included in a JWT token, so they must somewhat *transferable* as well.

What's the best way to design such a system? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you 2 different ways:

1. Write custom filter for your security framework. Setup pre authentication filter for URLs like `/company/{companyName}/**`, which will fill your context or token with all authorities user has for current company.
2. If you have complex logic for extracting authorities (e. g. can user view transaction or no), then it's probably better to move it to service layer and check authorities on demand before executing main logic.

Every modern security framework supports filters or something similar, so you should try to go with 1st option.